# react js variable can not shown in alert

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react.js and dealing with the below code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    state = { 
        counts:1,
        tags:['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3']
     };

    incrementIt() {
        this.state.counts++;
        console.log("counts value is ", this.state.counts);
     }

     btnClick(){ 
        this.incrementIt = this.incrementIt.bind(this);
         return (
             <div>
                 <button onClick={this.incrementIt} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Click me</button>
             </div>
         )
     }

     render(){
         return(
             <div>
                 {this.btnClick()}
             </div>
         )
     }
}

export default Counter;
```

I'm expecting counts shows in the alert window but not working, while it works when switch back to console.log(). How comes?

Comment: Use [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to manipulate state in React

Comment: There is a _lot_ wrong with this code. You can't just access the state variable to change state, don't use bind, use arrow functions, declare your state in a constructor that falls through to Component, etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to clean up some of that code: use `setState`, don't directly manipulate state. Also, assign that state in your constructor; don't use `bind`; and remember that if you want to see state changes, you need to wait until the state actually updates (which you can do with a function as second argument to `setState`)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Counter extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            counts: 1
        };
    }

    increment(evt) {
        let curCount = this.state.count;
        this.setState({ counts: curCount + 1}, () => {
            console.log(`after incrementing, counts value is ${this.state.counts}.`);
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={evt => this.increment(evt)} className="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Click me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: It doesn't work if replace console.log() with alert().

Comment: Never, _ever_, use alert(). Don't use it, don't look for it, don't ask about it, alert() is not a function that is part of modern Javascript, it is a _really old function_ that locks up an entire browser, and you should never force that onto someone, including yourself.  Anything you want to use alert for, you should use the console API for, and it'll do it better.